# TabBar black screen and no tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have this code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

    let listTableViewController = ListTableViewController()
    listTableViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .Contacts, tag: 0)
    var navViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: listTableViewController)
    tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(navViewController)

    let galleryViewController = GalleryViewController()
    galleryViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .Featured, tag: 1)
    navViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: galleryViewController)
    tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(navViewController)

    let serviceViewController = ServiceViewController()
    serviceViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .More, tag: 2)
    navViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: serviceViewController)
    tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(navViewController)

    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
```

But when app starts and logo is gone i've got only black screen and no tabs on the tab bar, but i want to see at least the empty table view from ListTablevViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your projects and it seems that the appending of viewControllers doesn't work properly since tabBarController.viewControllers is nil somehow. I did this little test, which works fine:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

        let listTableViewController = ListTableViewController()
        listTableViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .Contacts, tag: 0)
        let navViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: listTableViewController)
        tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(navViewController)

        let galleryViewController = GalleryViewController()
        galleryViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .Featured, tag: 1)
        let navViewController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: galleryViewController)
        tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(navViewController)

        let serviceViewController = ServiceViewController()
        serviceViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .More, tag: 2)
        let navViewController2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: serviceViewController)
        tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(navViewController)

        let controllers = [navViewController, navViewController1, navViewController2]

        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
        tabBarController.viewControllers =  controllers
        window!.rootViewController = tabBarController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()


        return true
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :)